# Calculating distance using trigonometry in 3D

Tags: math, 3d, trigonometry

I'm being quite dim - I can't figure out what should probably be a fairly trivial trig problem.

Given cartesian coordinates (x, y, z), I would like to determine a new coordinate given a direction (x, y and z angles) and a distance to travel.

```
class Cartesian() {
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;
  int z = 0;
  int move (int distance, int x_angle, int y_angle, int z_angle) {
    x += distance * //some trig here
    y += distance * //some trig here
    z += distance * //some trig here
  }
}
```

Ie, I want to move a given distance from the origin in a given direction, and need the coordinates of the new position.

This is actually for a JavaScript application, but I just need a bit of psuedocode to help me out.

Thanks

Comment: How are you measuring your X, Y, and Z angles? What are they relative to?

Comment: Erm, measuring in degrees, relative to their respective axes. Is that what you mean?

Perhaps I should have been clearer and called the x_direction variable x_angle etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've stated the problem, it seems that "direction cosines" make the most sense.

Assuming `x_angle` is the angle in radians between the target direction and the X
axis, etc.:

```
dc_x = cos(x_angle);
dc_y = cos(y_angle);
dc_z = cos(z_angle);

delta_x = dc_x * distance;
delta_y = dc_y * distance;
delta_z = dc_z * distance;

x += delta_x;
y += delta_y;
z += delta_z;
```

Comment: Surely distance traveled would therefore be greater than indended. Eg: Take distance = 2, x_angle = 10, y_angle = 20, z_angle = 60, then sqrt(delta_x^2 + delta_y^2 + delta_z^2) = 2.90... > 2

Comment: @foodwagon: There are only two degrees of freedom for your three angles:  they must obey the constraint that dc_x^2 + dc_y^2 + dc_z^2 = 1.  So (x_angle, y_angle, z_angle) = (10 deg, 20 deg, 30 deg) is not a valid set of direction angles.  Try some angles that satisfy that constraint, and you'll see that it works.

Comment: "two degrees of freedom" - that's what I couldn't get my head around. Think I've got it know, cheers!

Comment: it seems like the OP now understands the problem, I suspect the original intent is to have x_a, y_a and z_a to be Euler angles rather than direction cosines. In this case, a different equation is required (a DCM multiplication mayb?). Further, if my assumption is correct, then the z_angle is actually redundant since, as you mentioned in your comment, there are only 2 DOF available.